# AppleScriptEngine in java jar is not working, what am I missing?

Tags: java, macos, scriptengine

I am trying to incorporate Apple's script engine in my java app developed for macOs. I use eclipse to develop and when I run a debug build from eclipse all the Apple Script functions work.

As soon as I export it to an external jar and run that on the same machine they do no longer work.

I've searched and found some issues which I all tried, here is a summary:

- using getEngineByName("AppleScriptEngine") now.
- Adding the META-INF file javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory with the contents: apple.applescript.AppleScriptEngineFactory
- cleaning and rebuilding several times
- I opened the jar to see if the META-INF file is present and it is.
- searched in /System/Library/Java/Extensions/ for a applescript jar file but it was not there.
- I also searched for the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines to see if it is there but also not the case

It is still not working. So I do not know what the difference is exactly between eclipse debug run and running a jar in macOs but there has to be something I am missing.

As far as I can figure out it seems that the apple scripting class is not installed but then how does eclipse use it?

As I understand there is a difference between java JRE versions so I am in need of a solution for all of them because I do not know what systems are running my app.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: were you able to find any answers?